# Convert to criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I write criteria query to this following sql query.

```
select i.item_id,i.item_name,l.item_price 
from items i,pricelists l,sections s 
where i.id=100 and l.item_id=100 
and i.item_id not in (select s.item_id where s.id=100);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: add the mappings so we can see it

Comment: is you question mainly around how do you do the `not in` ? otherwise its a simple create criteria on Item and put restrictions..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to an article on some basic [Hibernate Criteria examples](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/), and here's a link to [a question here on SO where the "NOT IN" was solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220901/how-to-achieve-not-in-by-using-restrictions-and-criteria-in-hibernate).