# NOT IN in Hive QL

Tags: sql, hive

I'm converting a SQL Server stored procedure to HiveQL.

How can I convert something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (7,6,5,4,2,12)
```

Comment: @bonCodigo, Why was this retagged with hibernate?  That's not the same as hive.

Comment: NOT IN is now supported in Hive.  See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Answer (score -4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql) it says you can use `not in`:

**The negated forms can be written as follows:**

```
from DomesticCat cat where cat.name not between 'A' and 'B'

from DomesticCat cat where cat.name not in ( 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz' )
```

Are you getting an error when you try your query in the question?

Please try based on the references as well.

- [Reference 1](http://www.coderanch.com/t/217898/ORM/databases/clause-HQL).
- [NOT IN Clause in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416974/not-in-clause-in-hql).

Comment: The original question was about HiveQL, not HibernateQL

Answer (score 5):

NOT IN is now supported in Hive.  See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT array_contains(array(7,6,5,4,2,12), id)
```

Comment: upvoting because NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS solves another problem of neither A nor B should be present in an array..          like  NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS(Array, A) and NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS(Array, B)