# Is there something like nor to Criterion in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 3.3.1 and I need to get a list of entites which don't satisfies a `criterion`.

I've written my own `Criterion` implementation, called `SimpleTemplateCriterion` for an often use-case and I'd like to know am I going to have to write something like `NotSimpleTemplateCriterion` to use it for all entities not satisfying the `SimpleTemplateCriterion` criterion?

The thing I'd like to avoid code duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Restrictions.not**, you can pass to it your criterion, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220901/how-to-achieve-not-in-by-using-restrictions-and-criteria-in-hibernate).